# puts self getting called without any external call in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
class Hello
  puts self
end
```

running this code outputs `Hello`. But who does this call? I have not created any object or calling any class method.

Answer (score 5):

> In Ruby, class and module definitions are executable code.

[Reference](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/classes.html)

See also [this post](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/06/03/the-importance-of-executable-class-bodies/) on why this is useful

Comment: very confusing if you are from c++ background :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside a class `self` refers to the class. If you are not in a class (in irb for example), you will get `main`. Here are some examples

```
> puts self
main
=> nil
```

```
> class String
>  puts self
> end
String
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` in Ruby is basically like `this` in Javascript.  Since you're inside the Hello class, self = Hello.  Self gives you access to the current object, and since Ruby is an object-oriented language, classes are objects.  In Ruby, any class/instance methods are attributed to a class simply by defining them inside that class.  Therefore, the keyword `self` inside a class equals that class.  Just like in Javascript, if you console log `this` outside of any context, you'll get `window`, similarly, in Ruby, putsing `self` out of context will give you `main`